# OPEN CV Program execution error?

Tags: opencv

I am running my below code in eclipse, i have include the path and libraries successfuly, but when run the code it shows an error.

```
 #include <cv.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <highgui.h>
  //using namespace cv;
 int main()
{     
 Mat image;
 image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

 if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
  {
    printf( "No image data \n" );
    return -1;
  }

 namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 imshow( "Display Image", image );

 waitKey(0);
   printf("this is open cv programming");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error :      
`argc' undeclared (first use in this function) main.c /OpenCV2/src line 18 C/C++ Problem                                                
`argv' undeclared (first use in this function) main.c /OpenCV2/src line 16 C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main() signature is incomplete

try

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

these parameters represent:

```
argc  // an int indicating the number of arguments passed in to the function

argv[]  // an array of character strings, the actual arguments.
```

The first argument argv[0] is the program name ... so argc is always a minimum of 1.

The second argument, argv[1] will be the first argument your user passes in, bringing argc up to 2. That is what your program is expecting, a single argument from the user, argc == 2.

Comment: @PirFahimShah this error because you make the "using namespace cv;" commented , delete the comment and use namespace cv

Comment: @PirFahimShah are you sure you have installed openCV correctly? How do you know?

Comment: yeah i have installed it correctly, but i don't know the method that how to build, debug and run the project, i have followed some tutorial but i can't run this apps, please in just to show a simple image using open cv,step by step, plz plz

Comment: I see you have opened a new question. Can you accept my answer on this question (I correctly fixed that problem, and you should close the question as you have started a new one). Then we will take a look at your new version of the question.

Comment: @PirFahimShah. Please accept my answer (tick it) as it is correct.  Then delete your other question, because it is a mess, and start a new question. Explain that you are [following the tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html), show your code, explain what goes wrong. Take your time. You wouldn't have made the mistake in _this_ question if you had followed the guide slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version of OpenCV i.e. 2.4.3....however right now you can try to link the debug libraries e.g. opencv_core2.4.xd and run the program to get the Mat image format working.

what is the version of opencv you are using?
try the following code and test...get some picture and run it....

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat im = imread("C:\\some_picture.jpg");
  if(im.empty())
     return -1;
  imshow("TEST",im);
  waitKey();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: now i am getting some error in DEbug-->main.d file, please tell me the step that i could just run the open cv file..